# при выборе Maskedtextbox начинать с первого символа

Tags: c#, winforms

В наличии Maskedtextbox с датой (00/00/0000). Можно ли сделать так что бы при выборе этого элемента ввод всегда начинался с первого символа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void maskedTextBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
    {
        maskedTextBox1.Select(0, 0);
    });         
}
```